# integer rounding with parseInt in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code.

```
if( frequencyValue <= 30)
            leftVal = 1;
        else if (frequencyValue > 270)
            leftVal= 10;
        else 
            leftVal = parseInt(frequencyValue/30);
```

Currently if given the value 55 (for example) it will return 1 since 1< 55/30 < 2. I was wondering if there was a way to round up to 2 if the decimal place being dropped was greater than .5.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use a combination of parseFloat and Math.round

```
Math.round(parseFloat("3.567")) //returns 4
```

**[EDIT]** Based on your code sample, you don't need a parseInt at all since your argument is already a number. All you need is Math.round

Comment: from painful experience I would always recommend passing in the optional second param to force it to ten base: parseInt( myNum, 10 ) otherwise you can get in a whole world of debug pain when it tries converting strings that start with 0's etc which throw it all out into Hex mode and so on, a real head hurter...!

Comment: I agree, except that parseFloat doesn't have the radix parameter. It is just parseFloat(string).

Answer (score 7):

```
leftVal = Math.floor(frequencyValue/30 + 0.5);
```

Comment: This looks wrong.  Floor returns the lower value always, which is specifically what the questioner didn't want.

Comment: Ah, I see.  A rather hackerish way of doing it, but ok.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable technique. This is how round is implemented. From javadoc's Math.round: "The result is rounded to an integer by adding 1/2, taking the floor of the result, and casting the result to type int".

Comment: `Math.round` use the round to even convention, which in most cases is a bit weird, this does standard mathematical rounding.